Get unmatched strings present inside multiple like operator filter
I want to find the unmatched string from the table
select * from table WHERE column1 LIKE ANY(ARRAY['%test1%','%test2%','%test3%'])

Expected Result
Assume 

test1 is a MATCH
test2 is a Mismatch
test3 is a Mismatch

I need test2 and test3 value alone to be displayed in result (Comma separated or any other way)
What I tried
SELECT  
    regexp_replace(column1, '(test1|test2|test3)', '', 'g') AS non_matching_parts  
FROM  
    ip.table  
WHERE  
    column1 LIKE ANY(ARRAY['%test1%','%test2%','%test3%']);

I believe we need to move the values to a temp table and compare with the actual table, but I don't want temp table to be created

It works fine here; I cannot reproduce your result. Perhaps the text does not actually contain test1, but something different that just looks similar.
